# How to Use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3) to Send Welcome Messages with Amazon SES

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, next.js

I'm working on a Node.js application, and I need to send welcome messages to new users via email using Amazon Simple Email Service (SES). However, I recently received a warning stating that AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) will be in maintenance mode in 2023 and that I should migrate to AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3). I would like to know how to update my code to use AWS SDK v3 for sending welcome messages with SES.

Here's the initial part of my function that sets up the AWS SDK and SES:

```js
import { Db } from 'mongodb';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

export async function sendWelcomeMessages({ db }: { db: Db }): Promise<void> {
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });

  // Create a new SES object
  const ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' });

  // ... (The logic for sending welcome messages should go here)
}
```

Comment: We’re also going to be updating—is there no documentation on the V3 API?!

Comment: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascriptv3/example_code/ses#code-examples

Answer (score 2):

AWS SDK for JavaScript V3 docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html

SES: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/ses/

`SendEmailCommand`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/ses/command/SendEmailCommand/

Example:

```js
import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
const client = new SESClient(); // no need to set credentials/region as these are automatically set from environment variables

const input = {
  ... your parameters ...
}

const command = new SendEmailCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
```